# Problem with changing fonts

Tags: fonts

Upon launching emacs, I get this:

Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct

Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*--*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct

Next, when I go to Options --> Set Font/Fontset --> Font menu, I get 3 submenus: Misc, Courier and Fontset. I clicked on every item in each submenu, but it didn't change the font. How do I change a font, mine is too small?

The operating system is SunOS 5.10.

Comment: What is in your init file (or files it loads) that deals with fonts?

Comment: Surprisingly, I am not finding my init file anymore. I thought the file name was '.emacs' but I am not sure. I have a directory .emacs.d in my root, it contains only auto-save-list and tutorial.

Comment: Try `C-h v user-init-file`. But don't just post your init file - narrow it down to whatever part of it is causing the problem. And what happens if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If you see the same problem in that case then don't bother looking in your init file...

Comment: Indeed, 'emacs -Q' gives me the same problem.

Comment: And I tried 'C-h v user-init-file', it says the file name is ~/.emacs
There is no such file anymore, where can I get it?

Comment: Now I got a version of file '.emacs' from my colleague, placed it in my home dir, it did not help. Not that I see anything that has to do with fonts in that file.